# Should we undelete this answer about Jedi rank logos?

Tags: discussion, answers, deleted-answers

I saw the question pop up recently, and [one answer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/146253/70236) in particular drew my attention. It was a terrible answer at first, but it turned out that its poster was on the right track, and after a few edits it became a fairly good answer (referencing canon sources, unlike other answers to that question).

Since it's deleted (requires 10k rep to view), I'm providing it in its entirety here:

> I found a youngling logo, from ["The Gathering" episode (season 5, episode 6) of *The Clone Wars*](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/146253/70236), worn as a shoulder patch on students' cold weather gear.
>
> [image]
>    <sub>Image from the official website</sub>
>
> The [Wookieepedia article on younglings](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Jedi_youngling) provides a cleaner logo.

Problem is, that answer's been deleted (maybe rightly so, before the edits). I did flag for undeletion, yet was denied that. I really think this is a good answer right now. Can we please bring it back?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### No. Post a new answer.

The current version of the answer is a good one, but it has almost nothing in common with the [original version](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/revisions/146253/1):

> i found a logo its a youngling logo
>
> its the old republic symbol with a triangle around it
>
> here's the link
>
> https://www.google.com/searchq=jedi%20youngling%20logos&espv=2&rlz=1CADEAC_enUS707US707&biw=1366&bih=631&tbm=isch&imgil=L0OpWzeaEC6grM%253A%253BXnuqxtuF7a7DlM%253Bhttps%25253A%25252F%25252Fapathofajedi.wordpress.com%25252F&source=iu&pf=m&fir=L0OpWzeaEC6grM%253A%252CXnuqxtuF7a7DlM%252C_&usg=__0EiZXxlp9MVI1s5VtmbuONUyzM%3D&ved=0ahUKEwio78Tcr9HQAhWIzIMKHf1aB7IQyjcIMg&ei=uT0_WOiuBIiZjwT9tZ2QCw&safe=active&ssui=on#imgrc=L0OpWzeaEC6grM%3A
>
> sorry about the insult

The link does not work and that was the [only contribution of the user who posted that answer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/posts/146253/revisions). [Another user attempted to repair the link](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/revisions/146253/3), but the image linked in that revision does not match the one in the latest revision:

[image: old image]

[You added the image in the latest version of the post](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/revisions/146253/4), but instead of editing the post to something completely different than the original you should have just posted your own answer. This is the typical recommendation for such cases. For example, see [this meta answer](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/11031/31936) in which community consensus was that you shouldn't put more effort into editing a post than the OP put into it; I think this is a clear case of you putting in all the effort.

Comment: Thank you, I can see your point. Still, it seemed pointless to me to post an answer _after_ I'd edited all the good bits into that post, especially given it was good on its own, and respecting OP's intent doesn't seem a prerogative since they're unregistered and haven't been here for almost a year. Very well, I will post another answer.

Comment: @Gallifreyan Well, I don't think the original post was "good on its own". I would have rolled back your edit for conflicting with the OP's (presumed) intent (by changing the linked image) had the post not already been deleted. Trying to save this answer means you have to (1) edit the correct information in to the post, (2) petition on meta to get the community to undelete it, (3) get the community to upvote it to at least overcome its -2 score. Or you could just post your own answer and get the credit you deserve. The latter option seems a lot easier and better in every way.